# Why JMeter latency decreases but response times remain the same?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, latency, response-time

As I understand it, in JMeter:

Latency = Time from when the request is sent until the *first* response is received.

Response Time = Time from when the request is sent, until the *full* response is received.

I have a test that I've been running (non GUI mode) multiple times (exact same test every time), once without Google CDN and one with Google CDN.

With the Google CDN, I've seen Latency reduce by approx 50% (from ~900ms to ~450ms).

However, response time has stayed the same.

I would've assumed the response time would reduce/increase by the same amount that latency changes by?

Has anyone experienced this, or have any ideas as to why response time has remained the same?

Thanks :)